# TDD - Where to check if text file format is correct?

Tags: c#, tdd

I am working on a project that needs to read a text file with a specified format (variable declarations on the first line, assignation to them on the next lines) and then save the information in a class "A".

I don't get where should I check that the text file has the correct format: in the domain package, or in the BusinessLogic package. For example: The first line can never be empty. Should I check this in class "A" or in the logic package, in a class that acts as intermediary between the UI and the Domain?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are simply many ways to approach this.

Does your class `A` have "meaning" on its own? In other words: does it only exist to represent information from such files, or are these files just *one* way to create/populate instances of `A`?

If `A` is really independent of these files, then the parsing / validation code shouldn't go into `A` itself. Then it might make sense to have that code sit in a specific service class of its own, like `AFileReader` or something alike. That also upholds the single responsibility principle.

If `A` can only be "thought" in terms of such files, then you might want to have the reading/validation code in the same file, but again: probably in its own class. The responsibility of `A` is to represent that data.